# Does a portfolio have to be arranged in chronological order?

Tags: portfolio

I'm doing a web portfolio for my self and using my pieces within its own resume page. I know about the chronological method but haven't used it on my print version. I want to know if it is the recommended standard of arrangement or is it at the artist's discretion?

Comment: In all likelihood, prospective employers don't care when you did the work.

Answer (score 1):

There are no rules. Use whatever you feel best shows off your talents.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard.

- if showing the year of delivery is important, or showing many works across a long time span (10+ years), then yes chronological will make sense.
- if instead just showing off a limited number of jobs, either because you don't have too many or just want to showcase the best/most relevant ones, then you can showcase these sorted by relevance (best ones first).

Comment: People tend to have a short attention span, even recruiters etc. So if there's no specific format asked for, I'd suggest showing best ones first as well! :)